# Cannot style WPF TabControl's TabItem, changes are visible only in VS Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to remove all borders from `TabControl` (except the bottom one on tab item headers). So I selected "Edit template" in XAML Designer and made this change. I can see it happen in Designer, but when I launch my WPF app, the change is just not there. Tried rebuilding multiple times.

Also I want the whole `TabItem` content are with custom background color, is this even possible? So far I did not find any way how to achieve this.

Below is my changed `Border` and very long XAML `TabItem` template

```
<Border x:Name="mainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
```

-

```
<Style x:Key="ContentTemplateTest" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,6,2"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            **<Border x:Name="mainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">**
                                <Border x:Name="innerBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}" Margin="-1" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,0,-2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,0,-2,-2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-2,-2,-2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the next items I changed the tab item background and removed all borders except the one underneath the tabs and gave custom background color, *these elements are already present when overiding the template by default*.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="LightCyan"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
```

Note: the order of border values goes like this `Value="LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM"`

### Result

[image: result]

### Full example

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--Change background color here--> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="LightCyan"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
    <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}"> 
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}"/>
        <!--Change border here-->
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="contentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TabControl Height="100" Margin="10" Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle1}">
        <TabItem Header="One">
            <TextBlock Margin="10">Tab One</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Two">
            <TextBlock Margin="10">Tab Two</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Three">
            <TextBlock Margin="10">Tab Three</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

## Change borders

In order to change the borders for a selected tab, you have to go in the *multiDataTrigger* where the condition **binding** is `IsSelected` and **Value** is `True`.

*Note: The multidatatrigger you will be changing also depends on where you have your tabs so also check out Top, Left, Right, Bottom, since each one can have its's own settings.*

```
 <MultiDataTrigger>
     <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
     </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
     <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,0"/>
     <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
     <!--The border value's when the tab is selected-->
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
 </MultiDataTrigger>
```

**Result**

[image: result2]

Comment: Thanks @Jim, I finally changed background :-) Can you help with the border around headers? "One", "Two" and "Three" in your example. I need to have only bottom border around the active one. That is what works only in Designer as I wrote previously.

Comment: @Filip change the border value's in the second last setter in the code you had provided. ;-)

Comment: @Filip update my answer with where you change the borders of a selected tab.

Comment: fantastic! Everything works now :-) Thank you very much.